# Weird Watchkit and NSTimer Issue

Tags: ios, nstimer, watchkit

I am playing around with WatckKit, using an NSTimer to present an interface controller modally and that all works fine but I'm running into a weird issue.

I am using an integer to track the state of the controllers, **-2** means the watch interface is initialised, **-1** means that the user has dismissed the modally presented controller and **0** means that the modal controller is currently presented. I'm using these arbitrary values because I don't believe there is mechanism to notify the parent controller that the model controller has been dismissed.

The value is set to **-1** in the **willActivate** method of WKInterfaceController. From Apple docs :

> The willActivate method lets you know when your interface is about to
>   become visible on Apple Watch

So here is my code for a demo app. Note that the **presented** boolean is just used to ensure that the modal interface only gets presented once:

```
var i = -2
var presented = false
var timer:NSTimer?

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("time"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func time() {
        println("\(NSDate().description) : \(i)")
        if(!presented) {
            presentControllerWithName("Interface", context: nil)
            i = 0
            presented = true
        }
}

override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        if(i == 0) {
            i = -1
        }
}
```

Now if we observe the output given by the println, here is what I get:

```
2015-05-23 02:22:16 +0000 : -2
2015-05-23 02:22:16 +0000 : -2
2015-05-23 02:22:18 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:18 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:20 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:20 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:22 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:22 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:24 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:24 +0000 : -1
2015-05-23 02:22:26 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:26 +0000 : -1
2015-05-23 02:22:28 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:28 +0000 : -1
2015-05-23 02:22:30 +0000 : 0
2015-05-23 02:22:30 +0000 : -1
```

At the start we get **-2** printed, this is fine as that's what the integer was initialised as. Then the modal interface is presented, and the value changes to **0s**. When the interface is dismissed, **willActivate** is called and it changes the value to **-1** but in the console outputs, the value oscillates between -1 & 0 ? I have no idea why this happening. Another issue is why the values are being printed twice every 2 seconds?

Comment: Looks like your timer is initialized twice for some reason. Also, the timer is still running when your modal viewController is presented and still calling the time() function in the background repeatedly. Maybe you should invalidate it before presenting the other viewController.

Comment: Finally discovered that there was nothing wrong with application itself, but rather how Xcode was handling launching the WatchKit Extension on the Watch device. Xcode is very inconsistent in launching the app on the Watch once you run, so in my impatience I'd launch it myself. This somehow triggered launching of two instances of the app, I don't know how, but that was the reason for the double outputs! So when I let Xcode do it's thing, and launch the watch extension itself, everything works fine!